# Stack shape (geometry) and raster (NetCDF) for visualization

Tags: python-3.x, shapes, python-xarray, cartopy

I have defined geometry in python as below, which consist of latitude and longitude.

```
geometries_1 = [{
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[
        [-80.53471347676384, -1.2500950457702227],
          [-35.53471347676384, -5.81052129709212],
          [-35.27104160176384, -4.497521499969107],
          [-80.18315097676384, 0.41972388143469946]]]
        }]
```

Suppose I have a NetCDF file (integration with xarray as shown below), and **I want to visualise the geometry as below** (*shapes below are hypothetical and are drawn using paint*) with nice latitude and longitude axis visualization. Grey boxes are the hypothetical shapes.

[image]

Can someone suggest any such way with integration to xarray's and cartopy?

Answer (score 0):

I think [salem](https://salem.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.3/) has what you're looking for. It has `Xarray` integration and it is very well documented and has key examples.